# Cannot correctly reference child elements of a div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply CSS to elements in a child div using the various 'combinator' selectors but none of them seem to be working. The WORKING code is:
[here](http://codepen.io/lonekorean/pen/YXxxyj)

For the purposes of my page, I want to put the radio buttons into their own div so that I can have them as a separate menu.

However, I cannot seem to get the CSS to access the element 'characters' when I put the menu into its own div.

```
#original:checked ~.characters [data-teams~="original"] h2,
#force:checked ~ .characters [data-teams~="force"] h2,
#factor:checked ~ .characters [data-teams~="factor"] h2,
#hellfire:checked ~ .characters [data-teams~="hellfire"] h2 {
display: block;
}
```

As you can see, the 'characters' element is accessed using the tilde (~) combinator,  which works fine when the 'characters' element is in the same div as the radio buttons.

After putting the radio buttons into their own div, I have tried other accessors for the 'characters' element ( <, +, etc) but nothing seems to be able to access that element.

What would be the correct markup to use in this case?

EDIT: non-working code [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJLrbK)

Comment: You can only access _siblings_ of an element using `~` and `+`. (That’s why they are called _sibling_ combinators – the clue is in the name …)

Comment: CSS cannot go up the DOM

Comment: If you view the working code, I'm not trying to reference UP, I'm still trying to reference down, it just isn't working. I will edit the main post with a link to the NON working code.

Comment: We also need to see your representative (minimal, "[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)") HTML in your question, not just linked-to elsewhere on the net. Questions - and answers - should stand alone (but with links to references, demos and so forth where it helps), in order that if, or when, content elsewhere is removed, deleted and for some reason inaccessible, your question remains understandable and of benefit to future users.

Comment: _“I'm not trying to reference UP”_ – but you _would need to do that_ to be able to accomplish what you want, since from the `input` element you would have to “go up” to the `div` first, before you can select other elements on the same level as that div.

Comment: What you _can_ do however, is leave the input fields on the level necessary to be able to select their siblings – and move the `label` elements somewhere else. The labels trigger a switch of the radio elements’ states on click, but they don’t need a specific DOM structure to do that, since their `for` element makes the necessary connection between input and label.

Comment: I've added an example of the code that does not work to the main post. The only difference is that there is a div around the menu elements.

Comment: keeping the label elements in the div and moving out the radio buttons does work somewhat, but leaves other parts of my site (mainly show all and hide all checkboxes) still not working.

Comment: No, you haven't; you've added *a link to* the non-working code to the post, what you need to do is [edit] the code into your question, so that we're not required to wander around the internet in order to help you. It's in your best interests to make it easy for us to help you, since that way you get faster, better answers. And you get to help future visitors to the site.

Comment: _“but leaves other parts of my site (mainly show all and hide all checkboxes) still not working”_ – well then maybe the code that accomplishes that functionality needs a little reworking as well … (But since you have not even shown us those, we can’t tell you what exactly might need changing.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only access siblings of an element using `~` and `+`. That’s why they are called sibling combinators – the clue is in the name …

You can not reference “upwards” in the DOM with CSS – but you would need to do that to be able to accomplish what you want, since from the input element you would have to “go up” to the div first, before you can select other elements on the same level as that div.

What you can do however, is leave the `input` fields on the level necessary to be able to select their siblings – and move the `label` elements somewhere else. The labels trigger a switch of the radio elements’ states on click, but they don’t need a specific DOM structure to do that, since their `for` attribute makes the necessary connection between input and label.

Then you still need to modify your code to format the labels according to the selected radio button a bit – but something like this would work: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqRKWm

The input fields have been moved before the labels, which are now grouped in a div – that makes formatting the following content based on the `:checked` state of the radio buttons still work the same way.

To format the labels based on the selected radio button now, you need to go “into” the div first, and then select the label element for the right radio button – that requires duplicating those selectors, so that you have one for each input-label-combination:

```
input#original:focus ~ div label[for=original],
input#force:focus ~ div label[for=force],
input#factor:focus ~ div label[for=factor],
input#hellfire:focus ~ div label[for=hellfire]{
  outline: 1px solid #fff;
}

input#original:checked ~ div label[for=original]::before,
input#force:checked ~ div label[for=force]::before,
input#factor:checked ~ div label[for=factor]::before,
input#hellfire:checked ~ div label[for=hellfire]::before {
  background-color: #c00;
}
```

Of course you might want to use a more specific selector at this point, to target labels within that specific div element only (by using an additional id or class in the selector).